# Find out the time after which the item is rendered

Tags: javascript, html, angular, performance, lighthouse

How do I know after what time the button appeared on my site?

The site uses Angular.

I hoped to use npm lighthouse and user-timings for this task, but they are only for Js.

Comment: maybe you can create a button component and use the `ngAfterViewInit` function in the same component to determine when the button is completed rendering

Comment: Like after how many seconds the button appeared?

Comment: I need to know this metric to understand speed, it is important for marketing

Answer (score 2):

use `performance` global object or test [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now).

The Performance interface provides access to performance-related information for the current page.

`console.time`

This API is really easy to use. Simply put console.time before and console.timeEnd after the code you want to measure, calling the function with the same string argument. You can use up to 10,000 timers simultaneously on one page.

The precision is the same as of the performance API but this again depends on the browser.

```js
console.time('test');
const len = 99 ** 2;
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  Math.sqrt(i);
}
console.timeEnd('test');
```